# Using Citrix StoreFront API endpoints?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, citrix, storefront

I'm trying to wire up a solution to use custom C# code to do the following:

1. Authenticate against a StoreFront server
2. Enumerate apps
3. Launch the ICAs

I am able to do this following their example using basic authentication (user/domain and password).  However, I want to know if there is a way to do this with other authentication mechanisms.  I have searched for any documentation surrounding the `/Resources/` directory of API endpoints with no success.  I am using the `/Resources/List`, `/Resources/PostCredentialsAuth/Login`, and `/Resources/LaunchIca` endpoints, so I know there are API endpoints to use.

Does anyone know where I can find more information about these endpoints?  My end goal is going to be passing credentials/certificates from a custom app to authenticate against StoreFront.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have not found this yet - I found references to those URLs in the WebAPI.pdf from the Citrix website. You have to have a Citrix login to access the documentation. Log into Citrix.com and select downloads, from the Find Downloads dropdown select Storefront/WebInterface, the WebAPI documentation is in the Storefront 3.0 API's along with the Store Services API documentation which is also helpful. Let me know if you cannot get to it and I can send it to you.

Comment: I had not run across this, this is extremely helpful!  Thank you very much!

Comment: Direct link https://www.citrix.com/downloads/storefront-web-interface/sdks/storefront-services-api-30.html